# VBA adding slicer to unspecified table

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Macro that opens pivot table data that I then need to use for financial reconciliation. I have to go through the same process 80 times but not in a loop as I need to make notes as to what I found. However only the first time works, with the second time getting when adding table slicers. To do with the name I believe.

If needed the table could be name with the value in cell D6, however I have no idea how to do that, any help would be appreciated.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).name), "YEAR"). _
Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75
```

Or the full code.

````
Sub FORMAT()

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).COPY
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.ShowDetail = True
    RANGE("AF2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    RANGE("D2").Select

    ActiveSheet.name = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    Columns("B:c").Select
    Selection.Columns.Group

    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Columns.Group

    Columns("L:N").Select
    Selection.Columns.Group

    Columns("T:V").Select
    Selection.Columns.Group

    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

    RANGE("A1").Select

    ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Clear

    ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Add2 Key:=RANGE("Q2:Q1000" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Add2 Key:=RANGE("R2:r1000" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveSheet.SORT
        .SetRange RANGE("a1:V1000")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1

    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    '''''''''''''

    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).name), "YEAR"). _
        Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75

    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).name), "QTR"). _
        Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "QTR", "QTR", 223.5, 488.25, 144, 198.75

    '''''''''''''

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.RANGE(Array("QTR")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.RANGE(Array("YEAR")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_YEAR").Slicers("YEAR").Left = 0
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_YEAR").Slicers("YEAR").Top = 0
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_YEAR").Slicers("YEAR").NumberOfColumns = 8
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_YEAR").Slicers("YEAR").ColumnWidth = 35.43
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("YEAR").Height = 56.69
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("YEAR").Width = 311.81

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.RANGE(Array("QTR")).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_QTR").Slicers("QTR").Left = 316.06
        ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_QTR").Slicers("QTR").Top = 0
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_QTR").Slicers("QTR").NumberOfColumns = 4
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_QTR").Slicers("QTR").ColumnWidth = 35.43
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("QTR").Height = 56.69
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("QTR").Width = 161.57
    RANGE("a5").Select
    ```
````

Comment: slicer names are unique, if you create the slicer for "Slicer_Year" the first time that will be its name, the second time will be "Slicer_Year1" and so on adding 1 to the last one.

Comment: So in terms in terms of the above, how do I do that. How do I rename a slicer based on a cell value?

Comment: on the name for the slicer, add a random number which will be holded in a variable and then look for the name + the vairable.

Comment: FYI - `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).name)` is the same as just `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)`

Comment: `SlicerCaches.Add2` returns a `SlicerCache` object, so you can capture this and use the reference to change the same as needed.  Similar with `Slicers.Add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple answer for this. Literally just substituting the first "YEAR" with "Activesheet.name"

```
'ORIGINAL'
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1), "YEAR"). _
Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , "YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75
```

```
'FINAL'
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1), "YEAR"). _
Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, , ActiveSheet.Name , "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75
```

Answer (score 0):

`SlicerCaches.Add2` returns a `SlicerCache` object, so you can capture this and use the reference as needed. Similarly `Slicers.Add` gives you a `Slicer` reference you can use directly without needing to know its name:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, scYear As SlicerCache, scQtr As SlicerCache
Dim slcYear As Slicer, slcQtr As Slicer

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wb = ws.Parent   'workbook with the activesheet

'...
'...

'create caches and slicers
Set scYear = wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(ws.ListObjects(1), "YEAR")
Set slcYear = scYear.Slicers.Add(ws, , "YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75)

Set scQtr = wb.SlicerCaches.Add2(ws.ListObjects(1), "QTR")
Set slcQtr = scQtr.Slicers.Add(ws, , "QTR", "QTR", 223.5, 488.25, 144, 198.75)

'''''''''''''

With slcYear
    .Left = 0
    .Top = 0
    .NumberOfColumns = 8
    .ColumnWidth = 35.43
    .Height = 56.69
    .Width = 311.81
End With

With slcQtr
    .Left = 316.06
    .Top = 0
    .NumberOfColumns = 4
    .ColumnWidth = 35.43
    .Height = 56.69
    .Width = 161.57
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've tried the above but, its the same as mine, its only working on the first sheet, not the remaining ones

Comment: What happens when it *doesn't* work -  are you getting an error or ?  Can you elaborate a bit on "not in a loop as I need to make notes as to what I found" ?

Comment: run time error 5 - Invalid call argument or procedure at

''''Set slcYear = scYear.Slicers.Add(ws, , "YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75)''''

The ideal way to do it from my point is to name the slicer with "year" and the sheet name. Which is a code like "abc001" 

Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: `Set slcYear = scYear.Slicers.Add(ws, , ws.Name & "_YEAR", "YEAR", 186, 450.75, 144, 198.75)`